# what is the best way to solve the big number string to long?

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I am working with  a problem.The following code works for small string but in this case I have to work with long numbers.what could be the best possible solution ?

**it gives error for very long string so how to approach to solve the best possible way. by the way it is UVA424. There are so many solution online .I like to solve my way so it is a portion of the code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerInquiry {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    long total = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String i = input.next();
     if(i.equals("0"))  break; 

        int size = i.length();
        if(size <=100 ){
        long a = Long.parseLong(i);
        total = total+a;
        }



    }
    System.out.println(total);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: the question is clear. it gives error for very long string so how to approach to solve the best possible way. by the way it is UVA424. There are so many solution online .I like to solve my way so it is a portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For big numbers you can use `BigDecimal`

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(0);
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String i = input.next();
        if (i.equals("0"))
            break;
        bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(new BigDecimal(i));
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("BigDecimal " + bigDecimal);
    System.out.println("Long " + bigDecimal.longValue()); // caution - narrowing
```